# If we know some infinite sum has finite limit, would this justify infinite limit sum?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose we know that
$$\lim_{j \to \infty}\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}x_i = L$$
where $L$ is finite real number.

Would the above imply that
$$\sum_{u=0}^{\infty}\lim_{j \to \infty}x_{j+u} = L$$
assuming $\lim_{j \to \infty}x_{j+u}$ exists for every $u\geq 0$ and is finite real?

Comment: Your first assumption can never happen unless $L = 0$. Since a false proposition implies anything, well, sure, the above does imply the other proposition.

Comment: How is $x_i$ related to $j$?

Comment: @N74 I edited the question. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @najibidrissi why do you think that the first assumption is not valid? For $x_i=k^i$ and $k<1$ the sum is $k^j \over 1-k$ and the limit is 0.

Comment: @N74 Yes, and the limit can only ever be zero. This is a basic fact about converging series. And if a series converge, its general term converges to zero, and so for $L=0$ the second equation is trivially verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$ converges, then it's a standard fact about converging series that:
$$\lim_{j \to \infty} \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_j = 0.$$
And besides if the series converges, then $\lim_{i \to \infty} x_i = 0$ too, so simply by shifting the sequence $\lim_{j \to \infty} x_{j+u} = 0$ too. Thus the consequence you want is indeed satisfied, because $\sum_{u = 0}^\infty 0 = 0$.

If the series doesn't converge, then I can't even make sense of the first assumption.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{j \to \infty}\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}x_i = L$

First off $\sum x_i = W$ only if $x_i \rightarrow 0$

Second $\lim_{j \to \infty}\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}x_i = L$ can only happen if $\sum x_i = W$ for some $W$.  Then $\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}x_i = W - \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}x_i$ so  $\lim_{j \to \infty}\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}x_i = W - \lim_{j \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}x_i = W - W = 0$.

If these are true then $\sum_{u=0}^{\infty}\lim_{j \to \infty}x_{j+u} = \sum_{u=0}^{\infty}0 = 0 = L$

So, technically, yes.  But not for any of the reasons you assume.